# Adding a Counter to a Text Sequence

Tags: javascript, html, css, counter

Currently I am developing a game I am using JavaScript for the Gameplay

One of the functions allows the user to see the sequence they must enter (It prints out the color they must click)

But The problem is sometimes they must hit the same circle twice etc and that is not that clear for the user.

So I was wondering if it is possible to add a counter to the sequence that displays something simple like

1.Red

2.Red

3.Blue

So They can see that It wants a second red etc

Here is a jsfiddle so you can see what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/uusL7hch/17/

The JavaScript File cut down to only the part where the code for displaying the name of the color is

```
        $.each(this.genSequence, function (index, val) { //iterate over each value in the generated array
            timerCount = index;
            setTimeout(function () {

                that.flash($(that.shape + val), 1, 300, val);
                if ($("#text").is(":checked")) {//Check Box Function

                $(".TextBox").children(":first").html('<b>' + that.colors[val - 1] + '</b>');
                }
            }, 500 * index * that.difficulty); // multiply timeout by how many items in the array so that they play sequentially and multiply by the difficulty modifier

        });

        // Wait to start timer until full sequence is displayed
        setTimeout(function () {
            that.timerInterval = setInterval(function () {
                that.countDown()
            }, 100)

            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".TextBox").children(":first").html('');
            }, 500);
        }, 500 * timerCount * that.difficulty);
    },
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Could you please shorten your code to the relevant code lines?

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel code cut down to get u to the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the line which outputs the text:

```
$(".TextBox").children(":first").html('<b>' + (index + 1) + ":" +that.colors[val-1]+'</b>');
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uusL7hch/18/

Comment: Perfect Something so simple had me stuck for about an hour now thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

U need to define css personal tag to your data list:

```
ol#your_list_name {
    list-style-type:decimal;
}
```

Comment: Thats no going to work as it is printing the javascript file, i would need a counter for each sequence